# Copy data from MongoDB to Azure Blob Storage via ADF (Azure Data Factory)

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to copy data from MongoDB to Azure Blob Storage

The process failed and I'm getting this error:

> Failure happened on 'Source' side.
> ErrorCode=MongoDbOperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=>Failed
> to operate data via MongoDB
> client.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Runtime.MongoDbAtlasConnector,''Type=System.InvalidOperationException,Message=Duplicate
> element name 'createDate'.,Source=MongoDB.Bson,'

Can it be resolved on the Azure side, maybe changing the mongodb connection string adding some options or another thing?

I don't see any Duplicate elements on the MongoDB collection.